# How to mirror a filesystem structure but without any content

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, mirroring

This is needed for backup purposes. Just the index of the entire fs structure.
I can do such image with a FAR plugin. How can the same be achieved in the GNUverse?

Mirroring means perfect copy, i.e. tstamps, attribs, octets etc..

Answer (score 3):

```
find $PATH -type d -exec mkdir -p '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';' \
                   -exec touch --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';' \
                   -exec chown --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';' \
                   -exec chmod --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';'

find $PATH -type f -exec touch --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';' \
                   -exec chown --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';' \
                   -exec chmod --reference='{}' '/$BACKUP_PATH/{}' ';'
```

For details about the `--reference` option see the documentation for [touch](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html), [chown](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html) and [chmod](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html) from coreutils (the default on most Linux distributions).

Comment: Wau, we are almost there. All rights as well as timestamps. Perfect mirroring.      Any ideas how these two missing lines could look like?

Comment: Hell, indeed everything's possible in the GNUverse. Thanks guys.

Comment: $BACKUP_PATH var isn't evaluating (

Comment: can someone write a simple script generating tarball?

Answer (score 3):

For **XFS** filesystems you can use [**xfs_metadump**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_metadump.8.html) and [**xfs_mdrestore**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_mdrestore.8.html) which will copy the filesystem metadata, but not its contents, to another filesystem (preferably empty).

#### Explanation

xfs_metadump is a debugging tool that copies the metadata from an XFS filesystem to a file.  It should only be used to copy unmounted filesystems, read-only mounted filesystems, or frozen filesystems (see [xfs_freeze(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/xfs_freeze.8.html)).  Otherwise, the generated dump could be inconsistent or corrupt.

xfs_metadump does not alter the source filesystem in any way.  The target image is a contiguous (non-sparse) file containing all the filesystem's metadata and indexes to where the blocks were copied from.  The content of the files will appear to be full of zeroes.

xfs_metadump needs to be run with `-o` to disable obfuscation of file names and extended attributes.

xfs_mdrestore restores an XFS metadump image to a filesystem image.  It *should not be used* to restore metadata onto an existing filesystem unless you are completely certain the *target can be destroyed*.

#### Usage example

```
# Create the destination filesystem
# 64 MBs could be enough for a source of 72 GBs with a couple of files.
# Use more to be safe (and check the destination afterwards).
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/dst.dsk bs=1M count=0 seek=64
mkfs -t xfs /tmp/dst.dsk

# Copy. Destination can be destroyed!
xfs_metadump -o /dev/disk/by-label/src - | xfs_mdrestore - /tmp/dst.dsk

# Mount
mkdir /tmp/dst
mount -t xfs -o loop /tmp/dst.dsk /tmp/dst
ls -l /tmp/dst
```

Regarding the content of the files, this is what `od -x` prints for one of the files:

```
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
3221376000
```

Comment: This looks a bit confusing to me. Lets apply Occam's razor. On top of that i've never seen any xfs. Maybe just good old ext?

Comment: [XFS](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/xfs/) is one of the most popular and oldest filesystem available for Linux. Though Red Hat Enterprise Linux added support for it only recently. Nevertheless Fedora and other distributions had support for it for ages.

Comment: @xelvet that's not what Occam's razor means.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
ls -Ral /$PATH > /backup_location/fs_index.txt
```

Of course you can add date etc at the end of that txt file!

Comment: Not really. Not just listing saved into a file. But actual fs directories and filenames have to be there.